# How to clear variable buffer without deleting it in batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am batch script to write a code which takes input in this manner

```
db-driver-classname="%db_name_i%"
db-password="%db_pass_i%"
db-url="%db_url_i%"
db-username=%db_user_i%
```

i am using echo  >test.conf

This function contains a set of echo commands in each line

```
:Conf_Body
echo %l1%
echo %l2%
echo %l3%
echo %l4%
echo %l5%
echo %l6%
echo %l7%
echo %l8%
echo %l3%
echo %l4%
echo %l5%
echo %l6%
echo %l7%
echo %l7%

exit /B 0
```

and then these entries with a proper body will be over-written in a conf file. The problem is when i try to print the details from that file in the same script then it shows the entry that was entered in previous attempt but the conf file is containing new entries.
SO what can i do in this case

Comment: Your question lacks the necessary code parts, and your question is a bit unclear. However, the solution should be [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/463115)